# Can't see circles in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, data-visualization

I'm trying to create a scatter plot and while my axes are rendered, I can't see any circles. I can't figure out what's wrong.

I realized that my data values are in string so I used '+' operator. Still doesn't work. **There is no error message. I can see the elements in debug window being created but they are not displayed.**

Here is my code:

```
function visualize(data) {

var margin = { top: 20, bottom: 80, right:50, left: 70 };
var width = 720 - margin.left + margin.right, height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left);

g=svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform","translate("+margin.left+","+margin.top+")");

var xScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain(d3.extent(data,function(d) {
    return +d.FTAG;
})).range([0, width]);

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0,d3.max(data,function(d) { return +d["AF"]; })]).range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale);

g.append("g").attr("class", "x-axis").attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")").call(xAxis);
g.append("g").attr("class", "y-axis").attr("transform", "translate(0,0)").call(yAxis);

d3.selectAll("dot").data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .append("circle")
    .attr("r", 20)
    .attr("cx",
        function(d) {
            return xScale(+d.FTAG);
        })
    .attr("cy",
        function(d) {

         return yScale(+d.AF);
    })
    .style("fill",
        function(d) {
            if (+d.AF >= 20) {
                return "red";
            } else
                return "steelblue";
        })
    .style("stroke","black")
    .style("stroke-width",1.5);
}
```

Comment: Where is your `data`? You have to post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), otherwise it's very difficult to help you.

Comment: It's in a tsv format. Localhost.

Comment: And how this information helps? Please, read the page I linked above.

Comment: When I debug, I can see my data being loaded. Using d3 v4.

Answer (score 3):

In your code...

```
d3.selectAll("dot")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
```

... doesn't append groups anywhere.

It has to be:

```
svg.selectAll("dot")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
```

Since `svg` is the selection that appends an SVG to the `<body>`.

Comment: Wow, I've got a *"thanks"*! (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349158/is-this-serial-upvoting#comment473065_349158)

Comment: Yeah, I know I can't upvote your answer. But I tried :p

Comment: @MohitMotwani Sorry, I was not complaining about you (I know you can't upvote, because your RP < 15), that was just a joke in the Meta...

Comment: Yeah, I understood that.